# Definition for the max number of entity groups accessed in an ndb transaction?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb

From [What can be done in a transaction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Python_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction) (highlight from me):

> All Datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in
>   the same entity group if the transaction is a single group
>   transaction, or on entities in a maximum of **twenty-five** entity
>   groups if the transaction is a cross-group (XG) transaction.

Is there an actual definition corresponding to that 25 number that I can reference in my python app code? Or an API call returning it? I'd prefer to use one, if available, rather than create my own definition of it, just in case Google decides to change it down the road...

Update: To clarify, I'm talking about the equivalent of `_MAX_EG_PER_TXN` which I just spotted in `LiveTxn._GetTracker()` from the SDK's `google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stub_util.py` file:

```
      if self._allow_multiple_eg:
        Check(len(self._entity_groups) < _MAX_EG_PER_TXN,
              'operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.')
```

As a side note it'd be great for debugging if the tracked groups info from `self._entity_groups` could be somehow accessed when such exceptions are raised.

Comment: Wow 25 entity groups.  It used to be only 5, well that was once they added XG transactions ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity-Groups are the top level entities (no parent/ancestor). Every child entity that references it as a ancestor falls into the same Entity-Group.

There is not a programmatic way to ask the API to get a count, but you should be able to determine it in your own code either through explicit design:

- No more than 25 entities in a transaction if using top-level entities
- No more than 25 distinct parents if using child entities

The definition of Entity-Groups is baked into the underlying [Megastore](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36971.html) storage layer and so is unlikely change in any way other than us increasing the limit or removing the limit.

**EDIT:** FR logged: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/121

Comment: This answers the question of how to count the groups :) I am already working on an explicit design to achieve that, I was just looking for a programmatic definition of that 25 value, to use in that design.

Comment: Fair enough. It's not an unreasonable request to have an constant for it. I'll think about where I should file the request :D

Comment: Cool, thx! This also answers my question :) Pls update the answer with a pointer to the tracking issue, if/when available, so it can be star'd. Thx.